# Running scanf or gets from powershell hangs

Tags: c, powershell, stdio

We have a code that we wish to port to an environment whose main CLI is PowerShell. It had some problems so I've narrowed the code to the simplest:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    int ch =0;
    printf("hello world");
    while ((ch = getchar()) != '\n' && ch != EOF)
        printf("%c", ch);

    return 0;
}
```

This app compiles as a Win32 console app in VS2015 and runs as expected on cygwin, VS debugger, cmd, but when I run it from Powershell it gets into an infinite loop until I press CTRL+C.
I've searched all around for alternatives, replacement input functions, but basically we want to keep our code multi-platform and in plain C (no .NET functions etc). 
Same issue happens with simple programs that use functions that read from stdin such as scanf, gets.
How can we make this simple program run under powershell?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**
I was able to get this app running in the regular Powershell on a PC, I was using Powershell ISE before and it still doesn't work there.

But when using the same app on a remote powershell from a Windows 10 IoT dashboard (my final destination for this project)- The behavior is still not as expected.

Comment: Did you try entering a newline (by pressing ENTER key) or send EOF (by pressing ctrl+D)?

Comment: You mention `gets()` and you shouldn't because it's no longer part of the standard library.

Comment: @P.P. on windows CTRL+D is actually CTRL+Z

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed. I often forget that.

Comment: are you sure the code isn't just buffering the output? there are no `\n` in your output calls

Comment: Try `printf("%c", ch);` --> `{printf("%c", ch); fflush(stdout);}`

Comment: @P.P, Chris Turner, chux - tried your suggestions and it didn't work in Powershell.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi - is there any alternative you recommend instead?

Comment: @P.P. you can forget CTRL+Z AND powershell altogether. This pseudo unix crap from Microsoft just sucks.

Comment: According to the OP it runs in cmd

Comment: @jreing Yes `fgets()` which takes the buffer size as a parameter and is hence safer.

Comment: try `printf("hello world\n");` (adding newline) and tell us if that prints

Comment: your code compiled with gcc works fine in my machine using powershell `PS S:\> .\a.exe
hello world
hello you
hello you`

Comment: What version of powershell?

Comment: I use windows 10

Comment: I compile with VS2015. Perhaps i should try gcc.

Comment: @Iharob Al Asimi: fgets() does the same, when compiled in VS.

Comment: @jreing I didn't mean that it would fix the problem, you need to check how *powershell* buffers IO which has to be the problem. But I consider this to be very strange, and wouldn't expect it. So you need to post a [mcve] so that others can, 1. Confirm that the behavrio truly occurs or, 2. Find a mistake in your code and tell you how to fix it. For now, your reported behavior doesn't make sense in my opinion.

Comment: Posting some exact keystrokes used as input used and output seen would add clarity.  AFAIK, no output is ever seen including `"hello world"`